# Use of Google Fit Api

Tags: android, google-fit, google-fit-sdk

I am going to develop Health Application on Android Platform.which read data from wearable device and update on server.
Can I use Google Fit apis to read Data of wearable device sensor for my own application?

Answer (score 0):

From Google Fit Developers Website:

> The Google Fit APIs for Android are part of Google Play services and are supported in Android 2.3 (API level 9) and higher. Google Fit on Android consists of these APIs:
>
> The Sensors API provides access to raw sensor data streams from sensors available on the Android device and from sensors available in companion devices, such as  **wearables**.

Comment: is Fitbit device support GoogleFit Api?

Comment: stackoverflow is not a place to ask this kind of questions. google it and you will find the answer !